# trying to center a css menu made on purecssmenu.com

Tags: css, menu, alignment, center

i have a menu that i generated on purecssmenu.com and im having trouble trying to center it on my page here is the code...

```
<!-- Start PureCSSMenu.com STYLE -->
        <style>
        #pcm{display:none;}
        ul.pureCssMenu ul{display:none}
        ul.pureCssMenu li:hover>ul{display:block}
        ul.pureCssMenu ul{position: absolute;left:-1px;top:98%;}
        ul.pureCssMenu ul ul{position: absolute;left:98%;top:-2px;}
        ul.pureCssMenu,ul.pureCssMenu ul {
            margin:0px;
            list-style:none;
            padding:0px 2px 2px 0px;
            background-color:#000000;
            background-repeat:repeat;
            border-color:#000000;
            border-width:1px;
            border-style:solid;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu table {border-collapse:collapse}ul.pureCssMenu {
            display:block;
            zoom:1;
            float: left;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu ul{
            width:80.85000000000001px;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu li{
            display:block;
            margin:2px 0px 0px 2px;
            font-size:0px;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu a:active, ul.pureCssMenu a:focus {
        outline-style:none;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu a, ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a:hover, ul.pureCssMenu li.sep a:hover {
            display:block;
            vertical-align:middle;
            background-color:#000000;
            border-width:1px;
            border-color:#000000;
            border-style:solid;
            text-align:left;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding:2px 5px 2px 10px;
            _padding-left:0;
            font:11px Arial;
            color: #969696;
            text-decoration:none;
            cursor:default;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu span{
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu li {
            float:left;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu ul li {
            float:none;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu ul a {
            text-align:left;
            white-space:nowrap;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu li.sep{
            text-align:left;
            padding:0px;
            line-height:0;
            height:100%;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu li.sep span{
            float:none; padding-right:0;
            width:3px;
            height:100%;
            display:inline-block;
            background-color:#cccccc #111111 #111111 #cccccc;   background-image:none;}
        ul.pureCssMenu ul li.sep span{
            width:100%;
            height:3px;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu li:hover{
            position:relative;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu li:hover>a{
            background-color:#000000;
            border-color:#000000;
            border-style:solid;
            font:11px Arial;
            color: #ffa500;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu li a:hover{
            position:relative;
            background-color:#000000;
            border-color:#000000;
            border-style:solid;
            font:11px Arial;
            color: #ffa500;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a {
            color: #666 !important;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu img {border: none;float:left;_float:none;margin-right:2px;width:16px;
        height:16px;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu ul img {width:16px;
        height:16px;
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu img.over{display:none}
        ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a:hover img.over{display:none !important}
        ul.pureCssMenu li.dis a:hover img.def {display:inline !important}
        ul.pureCssMenu li:hover > a img.def  {display:none}
        ul.pureCssMenu li:hover > a img.over {display:inline}
        ul.pureCssMenu a:hover img.over,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover ul img.def,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover img.over{display:inline}
        ul.pureCssMenu a:hover img.def,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover ul img.over,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover a:hover img.def{display:none}
        ul.pureCssMenu a:hover ul{display:block}
        ul.pureCssMenu span{
            display:block;
            background-image:url(./images/arr_white.gif);
            background-position:right center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
           padding-right:12px;}
        ul.pureCssMenu li:hover>a>span{ background-image:url(./images/arrv_white.gif);
        }
        ul.pureCssMenu a:hover span{    _background-image:url(./images/arrv_white.gif)}
        ul.pureCssMenu ul span,ul.pureCssMenu a:hover table span{background-image:url(./images/arr_white.gif)}
        </style>
<!-- End PureCSSMenu.com STYLE -->
```

and here is the html, witch is probably not even needed in this posted but i figure i would include it.. i just want that menu centered inside my website.

```
<!-- Start PureCSSMenu.com MENU -->
<ul class="pureCssMenu pureCssMenum">
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="home.html" target="scare">home</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">about</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#"><span>haunts</span><![if gt IE 6]></a><![endif]><!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
    <ul class="pureCssMenum">
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">2009</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">2010</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">2011</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">2012</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">studio</a></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#"><span>products</span><![if gt IE 6]></a><![endif]><!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
    <ul class="pureCssMenum">
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">nightmares</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">hauntworks</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">atmosfears</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">frightwears</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#"><span>links</span><![if gt IE 6]></a><![endif]><!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
    <ul class="pureCssMenum">
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">haunts</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">suppliers</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">resources</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
<a id="pcm" href="http://www.purecssmenu.com/">CSS Drop Down Menu by PureCSSMenu.com</a>
<!-- End PureCSSMenu.com MENU -->
```

thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you include in your post what you have tried to do to center the menu. Then people will be more likely to help. If you're new to CSS, check out http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround it with a div and then center the div.

```
<div class="table">
```

Then add the following to your css

```
.table {
    display: table;   /* Allow the centering to work */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

See the working example. 
http://jsfiddle.net/uh2Jt/3/

Comment: thanks everyone, got it. the float needed to be none and the display was changed to inline-block

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.pureCssMenu,ul.pureCssMenu ul {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution. The issue I found was that the `.pureCssMenu` was being `floated left`. I just overwrote that so you can see where it was happening. Probably a better idea to edit the css properly though, if you don't understand let me know and I'll explain more. Also wrapped it in a `div (.centerme)` with `text-align: center;`

**http://jsfiddle.net/nYbcW/**

```
.centerme{
    text-align: center;
}
ul.pureCssMenu {
    float: none !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-align:center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setting:

```
ul.pureCssMenu,ul.pureCssMenu ul {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

won't work since it looks like the menu's position is set to `absolute`. Instead of messing with the menu's code, you can just put it in a wrapper div like so :

```
<div class="menuWrapper">
    all the html for the menu
</div>
```

and then using this CSS, with whatever width works for you:

```
.menuWrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Check out the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mCmfU/

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest you can get:

```
ul.pureCssMenu,ul.pureCssMenu ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    float: none;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Just adjust the width and the height to your need.

**Note:** you can add this bit of code to the bottom of you styles so you don't need to bother searching for it.